# Правка мобильной верстки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, адаптивность

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: сверстал десктопную версию макета, принялся делать адаптив. По итогу все сделал, и когда на компе проверяю верстку, изменяя масштаб все ок. Однако, как только залил все на хостинг, то при просмотре с мобилки выявилась следующая проблема:

[image: Указал стрелкой на линию, которая должна быть ниже, на уровне тонкой оранжевой линии]

При этом, с компа отображается следующая картинка:
[image: То есть тут все корректно отображается. И на любом другом формате на компьютере все хорошо.]

Проблема в том, что у меня не получается на компе воссоздать проблему, которая есть на мобильном, а это, в свою очередь не позволяет мне решить этот вопрос. Пробовал менять стили у этой картинки, загружал другую и тд. Но все безуспешно.

```
<section class="header">
    <div class="header__abs-left">
        <img src="./src/icons/ecva_1.png" alt="ecva_1">
    </div>
    <div class="header__abs-right">
        <img src="./src/icons/ecva_2.png" alt="ecva_2">
    </div>

    <div class="header__line-left">
        <img src="./src/img/line_green04.png" alt="green">
    </div>
    <div class="header__line-left_blue">
        <img src="./src/img/line_blue.png" alt="green">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <div class="header__top">
                <div class="header__logo">
                    <a class="header__link" href="#">
                        <img class="responsive logo_1" src="./src/icons/logo.png" alt="logo">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="header__wrapper">
                    <div class="header__btn">
                        <button class="header__button open_consultation" data-modal="consultation">ЗАКАЗАТЬ ЗВОНОК</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="header__hamburger" id="hamburger">
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="header__phone">
                        <a href="tel:73852248673" class="header__tell">+7 (3852)  <span>24 86 73</span></a>
                        <a href="tel:73852248945" class="header__tell">+7 (3852)  <span>24 89 45</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="header__low">
                <div class="header__logo-wrapper">
                    <img class="responsive logo_2" src="./src/icons/logo_2.1.png" alt="logo_2">
                    <img class="responsive logo_3" src="./src/icons/logo_3.1.png" alt="logo_3">
                </div>
                <nav>
                    <ul class="header__menu">
                        <li class="header__menu_item"><a href="#" class="header__menu_link">главная</a></li>
                        <li class="header__menu_item"><a href="#" class="header__menu_link">о нас</a></li>
                        <li class="header__menu_item"><a href="#" class="header__menu_link">продукция</a></li>
                        <li class="header__menu_item"><a href="#" class="header__menu_link">услуги</a></li>
                        <li class="header__menu_item"><a href="#" class="header__menu_link">инсталляции</a></li>
                        <li class="header__menu_item"><a href="#" class="header__menu_link">статьи</a></li>
                        <li class="header__menu_item"><a href="#" class="header__menu_link">отзывы</a></li>
                        <li class="header__menu_item"><a href="#" class="header__menu_link">контакты</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="header__block320px">
                <button class="header__button open_consultation" data-modal="consultation">ЗАКАЗАТЬ ЗВОНОК</button>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="carousel">
    <div class="header__abs-right-low">
            <img src="./src/icons/ecva_color.png" alt="color">
    </div>
    <div class="home__wrapper">
        <ul class="home__submenu">
            <li class="home__submenu_item">
                <a href="#" class="home__submenu_link">Звуковое и музыкальное оборудование </a>
            </li>
            <li class="home__submenu_item">
                <a href="#" class="home__submenu_link">Изготовление, ремонт, комплектация</a>
            </li>
            <li class="home__submenu_item">
                <a href="#" class="home__submenu_link">Студия звукозаписи</a>
            </li>
        </ul>        
    </div>
        <div class="carousel__inner">
            <div>
                <div class="carousel__slide-two">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="carousel__two">
                            <div class="carousel__two_box">
                                <div class="carousel__two_top">
                                    <div class="carousel__two_logo">
                                        <img class="logo_1" src="./src/icons/slide_logo1.png" alt="logo1">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="carousel__two__desrc">
                                        Экспериментальное<br> 
                                        Творческое Объединение
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel__two_middle">
                                    <div class="carousel__two_logo">
                                        <img class="logo_4" src="./src/icons/slide_logo2.png" alt="logo2">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="carousel__two__desrc">
                                        Design Electronic<br> 
                                        Laboratory
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel__two_low">
                                    <div class="carousel__two_logo">
                                        <img class="logo_5" src="./src/icons/slide_logo3.png" alt="logo3">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="carousel__two__desrc">
                                        Лаборатория<br> 
                                        Акустического Дизайна                 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="carousel__slide-one">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="carousel__one">
                            <div class="home__text">
                                НАДЕЖНОСТЬ,<br>
                                <span>ПОМНОЖЕННАЯ НА</span> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="home__quality">
                                качество
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>

.header {
max-height: 123px;
padding: 21px 0;
background-color: #011a26;
position: relative;

&__top {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
&__logo {
    margin-left: 54px;
}
&__wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
&__btn {
    padding-right: 28px;
}
&__button {
    width: 164px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #0c2c56;
    border: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    cursor: pointer;
    &:hover, &:focus {
        background-color: #085086;
    }

}
&__phone {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    a {
        color: #4f6b76;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-align: left;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
        &:last-child {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        span {
            color: #f4b407;
            font-weight: 500;
        }
    }
}
&__low {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
&__menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    &_item {
        margin-right: 20px;
        &:last-child {
            margin-right: 0;
        }

    }
    &_link {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fefefe;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 500;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        &:hover {
            color: #f4b407;
        }
    }
}
&__home {
    background: url('/src/img/home.jpg')
}
&__abs-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 40px;
    
}
&__abs-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 58px;
    right: 40px
}
&__abs-right-low {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    right: 40px;
    z-index: 200;
}
&__line-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 108px;
    left: 265px;
    z-index: 200;
    &_blue {
        position: absolute;
        top: 107px;
        left: 290px;
        z-index: 150;
    }
}
&__logo-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    img {
        &:first-child {
            margin-left: 9px;
            margin-right: 6px;
        }
    }
}
&__block320px {
    display: none;
}
&__hamburger {
    display: none;
}
```

}

---

```
.home {
&__wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba($color: #085086, $alpha: 0.78);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding: 13px 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #fdb508;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;

}
&__abs-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 134px;
    right: 40px;
}
&__line-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 104px;
    left: 265px;
}
&__submenu {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    li {
        margin-right: 82px;
        &:last-child {
            margin-right: 0;
        }
        a {
            color: #acdbff;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 400;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-decoration: none;
            &:hover, &:focus {
                color: #ffffff;
            }
        }
    }
}
&__text {
    margin-top: 243px;
    text-shadow: 0 5px 7px rgba(17, 62, 77, 0.75);
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 67px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 55px;
    text-align: left;
    span {
        font-size: 45px;
    }
}
&__quality {
    margin-left: 139px;
    text-shadow: 0 5px 7px rgba(17, 62, 77, 0.75);
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 105px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

}

---

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
body {
    background: #011a26;
}
.container {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.header {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 26px 0 13px 0;
    nav {
        align-self: center;
    }
    &__wrapper {
        margin-right: 11px;
    }
    .logo_1 {
        max-width: 105px;
    }
    .logo_2 {
        max-width: 83px;
    }
    &__abs-right {
        top: 64px;
        right: -115px;
    }
    &__menu_link {
        font-size: 9px;
    }
    &__low {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }
    &__logo-wrapper {
        margin-left: 0;
        padding-left: 26px;
        img {
            &:first-child {
                margin-left: 0;
                margin-right: 5px;
            }
        }
        
    }
    &__menu {
        padding-left: 14px;
        margin-top: 14px;
    }
    &__menu_item {
        margin-right: 11px;
    }
    &__btn {
        position: absolute;
        top: 61px;
        right: 0;
        padding-right: 11px;
    }
    &__phone {
        padding-right: 0;
        a {
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    }   
    &__low {
        margin-top: 12px;
    }
    &__logo {
        padding-left: 59px;
    }
    &__button {
        width: 134px;
        height: 33px;
        font-size: 11px;
    }
    &__line-left, &__line-left_blue {
        top: 117px;
        left: -15px;
    }
}
.home {
    &__wrapper {
        padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    }
    &__submenu {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        li a {
            font-size: 10px;
        }
    }
    &__quality {
        font-size: 59px;
        margin-left: 121px;
    }
    &__text {
        margin-left: 72px;
        font-size: 38px;
        line-height: 31px;
        span {
            font-size: 25px;
        }
    }
}
```

}

---

```
@media (min-width: 322px) and (max-width:435px) {
.container {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.header {
    &__button {
        width: 120px;
    }
    &__menu {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    &__line-left,
    &__line-left_blue {
        top: 136px;
    }
    &__abs-right {
        top: 82px;
    }
    &__logo-wrapper {
        margin-left: 0;
        padding-left: 14px;
    }
    &__logo {
        padding-left: 47px;
    }
}
.home {
    &__text {
        margin-left: 14px;
    }
    &__quality {
        margin-left: 17px;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: А можно код увидеть?

Comment: Добавил. Прошу прощения, если много сбросил

Comment: вскрытие показало, что у Вас очень много разных условий `@media`. Еще можно попробовать убрать `position: absolute;`

Answer (score 1):

> Проблема в том, что у меня не получается на компе воссоздать проблему, которая есть на мобильном, а это, в свою очередь не позволяет мне решить этот вопрос. Пробовал менять стили у этой картинки, загружал другую и тд. Но все безуспешно.

В Safari на ios блок с адресом страницы не входит во Viewport.
Поэтому до тех пор пока вы не смахнете этот блок на устройстве, будет "кривое" отображение.

Как вариант, я бы посоветовал сделать привязку этой линии к какому-либо объекту, а не относительно экрана.

Comment: Ну я же задал ей абсолютное позиционирование относительно определенного блока. Или я не правильно понял?

Comment: @Aptero необходим код проблемного места и только того случая, где "сломалось" (слишком много ненужного кода). А вообще у вас всё через absolute сделано - даже корневой элемент - очень жесткая привязка. Попробуйте совсем от него отказаться.